# Python create a file in a specific directory

Tags: python, file, directory, path

I'm trying to create a file in a specific folder, but the file will create in the app's path no matter what.

```
path = os.getcwd()
while not os.path.exists(path + "\\testfolder"):
    os.mkdir(path + "\\testfolder")

test_folder_path = path + "\\testfolder"
test_file = open(test_folder_path + "test.txt", "w")
test_file.write("test")
test_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a slash at the end of the `test_folder_path` variable, so the created file path is `cwd\testfoldertest.txt` instead of `cwd\testfolder\test.txt`

Comment: Thank you , i can't belive i didn't see this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're missing a separator between the path and the file name. You could consider letting `os.path.join` do the heavy lifting for you:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
targetPath = os.path.join(cwd, testfolder);
while not os.path.exists(targetPath):
    os.mkdir(targetPath)

targetFile = os.path.join(targetPath, 'test.txt')
testFile = open(targetFile "w")
testFile.write("test")
testFile.close()
```